# Resource to find ductus of a symbol

Tags: software, fonts, stroke-order

Is theire any ressource (font, software) who give [ductus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ductus_(linguistics)) for a given character with both the strokes order and the way each stroke should be drawn?

I search it to make my own writing paper depending of the new symbols I learn.

So, the my goal is to make a little software (script) witch I give a symbol and it output a writing page. That’s why website is not really useful…

In bonus, if their is any free|open source software for this it would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like [Make Me a Hanzi](https://github.com/skishore/makemeahanzi) would be a good fit.

It contains beautiful vector graphics for Chinese characters, and it's free and open source ([license](https://github.com/skishore/makemeahanzi/blob/master/COPYING)).  [Hanzi Writer](https://hanziwriter.org/), for example, utilizes this database; see the [demo page](https://hanziwriter.org/demo.html).

I've used characters from Make Me a Hanzi, and converted them to tikz where I can edit them manually and use them in LaTeX documents, like this:

> [image: breakdown of the character 鲨]

Comment: Waw, this ressource is an absolute treasure. But, in order to print the ductus, does Make Me a Hanzi give a step-by-step image instead of animation? Or, at least a number on each stroke indicating the order? I am only able to generate animation with the demo.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this old thread](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/14101/stroke-order-database) here on chinese.stackexchange

Looks like you need a json database with the strokes for each character. If you can find such a database, then drawing the strokes one after the other shouldn't be too hard.

Then, in a webpage use javascript. If you don't want web-based output, maybe use Python PIL or cv2.

Personally, I just look on the web, for example [here](https://dict.baidu.com/s?wd=%E6%97%A5&ptype=zici) if I want to see the stroke order.

After a while, you get the hang of the stroke order for most characters, even if the particular character is new to you.

But I probably would not pass the Imperial Exam for Writing Chinese!